# How to check if text is present on a webpage?

Tags: php

how to check if text is present on a webpage using php and if true to execute some code?

My idea is to show some relevant products on the confirmation page after completing an order - if the name of the product is present on the page, then load some products. But I can't make the check for present text.

Comment: What have you tried so far? googling your exact question gives me several options you could pursue

Comment: if an order is completed, that means you have a product name, right ? Why don't you just match your results on that ?!

Comment: I can't find a function that searches for text on a page. Lets say I have a page with a text "This is my page". The goal is php to perform a check if  the page contains the text "This is my page" and if it finds it, to execute some code.

Comment: Maybe if u are using variables for outputing your text, you can use 'strpos' http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Cant he use file_get_contents and do a strpos or something like that to match the text ?

Comment: Something like  $handle=file_get_contents('mypage.php'); $a = 'This is my page';

if (strpos($a, $handle) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}

Comment: @Gorna-Bania have you tried file_get_contents ?

Comment: I found out that the code uses variables to output the text. thank you very much for the suggestions!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1** if you prepare your page in a variable then echo it at the end of the script like

```
 $response = "<html><body>";
 $response .= "<div>contents text_to_find</div>";
 $response .= "</body></html>";
 echo  $response;
```

**then** you can merely search the string with any string search function

```
if(strpos($response,"text_to_find") !==false){
    //the page has the text , do what you want
}
```

---

**Case 2** if you don't prepare the page in a string . and you just echo the contents and output the contents outside the `<?php ?>` tags like

```
<?php 
   //php stuff
?>
<HTML>
  <body>
<?php 
   echo "<div>contents text_to_find</div>"
?>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

**Then** you have no way to catch the text you want unless you use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

---

**Case 3** if you use output buffering - which I suggest - like

```
<?php
    ob_start(); 
   //php stuff
?>
<HTML>
  <body>
<?php 
   echo "<div>contents text_to_find</div>"
?>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

**then** you can search the output anytime you want

```
$response = ob_get_contents()
if(strpos($response,"text_to_find") !==false){
    //the page has the text , do what you want
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I use strcmp instead of strpos?

Comment: @Gorna-Bania No. `strcmp` is for comparing 2 strings. what you want is to search a string.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `buffer` your Output like so...

```
<?php

    ob_start();
    // ALL YOUR CODE HERE...
    $output = ob_get_clean();

    // CHECK FOR THE TEXT WITHIN THE $output.
    if(stristr($output, $text)){
      // LOGIC TO SHOW PRODUCTS WITH $text IN IT...
    }

   // FINAL RENDER:
   echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest solution is using php DOM parser:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/etc-etc-etc');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
$txt = '';
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $txt .= $div->textContent;
}
```

This way, variable $txt would hold the text content of a given webpage, as long as it is enclosed around div tags, as usually. Good luck!